# Reduce duplicate CSS code for checkbox / radio button group

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following CSS that styles checkbox and radio button groups, and I like to shorten it by combining the styles set for `.blg-buttons input[type=radio]` and for `.blg-buttons input[type=checkbox]`. Currently I write the styles out separately for these (even though the styles are the same for both) and am not sure the best way to combine them.

The code is made a bit longer by having nested spans, span:hovers, and :not(:checked) used in the CSS as well.

```
/* App-Wide Radio Button Group */
/* Padding on the Span - Margin on the Label */
/* ========================================= */
.blg-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
}

.blg-buttons input[type=radio] {
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.blg-buttons label {
    display: flex;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0.85vw;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0.2vw;
    font-weight: 700;
 }

.blg-buttons input[type=radio]+span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: .5vw;
    border-radius: .35vw;
    border: .15vw solid #333;
    /*width: 90%;*/
    /* text-align: center; <-- you don't need this with flex */
    color: #333;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
}

/* button colors */
.blg-buttons input[type=radio]:not(:checked) + span {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #EEE;
    color: #333;
}

/* button colors */
.blg-buttons input[type=radio]:not(:checked) + span:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #888;
}

/* button colors */
.blg-buttons input[type=radio]:checked + span{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #EEE;
}


.blg-buttons input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.blg-buttons input[type=checkbox]+span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: .5vw;
    border-radius: .35vw;
    border: .15vw solid #333;
    /*width: 90%;*/
    /* text-align: center; <-- you don't need this with flex */
    color: #333;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
}

/* button colors */
.blg-buttons input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) + span {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #EEE;
    color: #333;
}

/* button colors */
.blg-buttons input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) + span:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #888;
}

/* button colors */
.blg-buttons input[type=checkbox]:checked + span{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #EEE;
}
/* =========== */
```

i.e. Can I combine `.blg-buttons input[type=radio]:checked + span` and `.blg-buttons input[type=checkbox]:checked + span` into one group that is `.blg-buttons input[type=checkbox & radio]:checked + span`, or something like this?

Also am I able to nest things like this?:

```
.blg-buttons {
    label { }
    ... 
}
```

Any help with how to shorten this CSS in general is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following things

**CSS**

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] 
    { 
       //here should be your css
 }
```

**SCSS/LESS**

```
.blg-buttons {
  input[type=radio] {}
  input[type=checkbox] {}

}
```